# What would be correct regular expression to validate string with 4 parts separated by minus sign

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I would like to put together regex for validating string which comes in format `'FIXED-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA'` where `'FIXED'` part is fixed static string and other 3 parts can contain alpha numeric characters a..Z and 0..9.

I need regex pattern for JS and PHP.

Comment: We need you to try this in your own. We are here to **HELP**, not do your job for you. Once you have a VALID attempt at a solution, but can't it to work quite right, THEN you can come and ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
var re = /^FIXED(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}){3}$/;
```

You could as well use the charactergroup `\w` which usually is pretty much equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` but that might contain several characters (ASCII <> UTF) you might not want to have.

Comment: I think, it's better to add `^` and `$` at the start and at the end, respectively, because pattern is intended for validation.

Comment: And it is the same in PHP. So yeah that's the one you should use (did not see this one before I commented the other one).

Comment: @Talus that's not supported in JS, not entirely sure about PHP.

Comment: yeah that's why I deleted my comment. But yes [it is supported in PHP](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).

Comment: Thanks guys. Ended up with this in JS `value.match(/^DW7(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}){3}$/)`, seems to be working!

Comment: @PrimozRome If it's working, kindly accept the answer, to mark your problem as solved.

Comment: @Cristoph sure I always do after testing is done!

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be

```
~FIXED-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}~i
```

for php, JavaScript will be almost identical except maybe the modifier at the end (the `i`)

Comment: The modifier will be the same. The part that is different is the delimiter. Note that since you don't know what the FIXED part contains, it might be a bit risky to use `i` flag here.

Comment: Using `[[:alnum:]]` is wordier, but clearer.

Comment: @EricJablow: Not supported in JS RegExp.

Answer (score -1):

```
var my_re = /FIXED(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+){3}/
```

Comment: @nhahtdh it was stackoverflow template, i forgot to remove it when composed message.

Comment: this is almost correct, but in your case, it would also validate `FIXED-ZERFGD-AFGGGRZGTH-A-AZER` which is not the intended effect. Otherwise, it is globally correct. :)

Comment: @Talus: The requirement is not that explicit in the question, though.